# Error when I try to log in with a new user in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to write code to register then log-in users in Flask. I want to register an user and then redirect it to the main page, but I'm getting this error and I don't know how I can fix it, thank you.

```
[2023-03-04 17:56:58,029] ERROR in app: Exception on /sing-up [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Pourya\PycharmProjects\websiteproject\venv\lib\site-   packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1964, in _exec_single_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "C:\Users\Pourya\PycharmProjects\websiteproject\venv\lib\site-  packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 747, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.

  File "C:\Users\Pourya\PycharmProjects\websiteproject\venv\lib\site-    packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 747, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
[SQL: SELECT user.id AS user_id, user.email AS user_email, user.password AS user_password, user.name AS    user_name_1, user.last_name AS user_last_name, user.user_name AS user_user_name, user.confirmed AS  user_confirmed, user.confirm_cod AS user_confirm_cod, user.joined_date AS user_joined_date 
FROM user 
WHERE user.id = ?]
[parameters: (<User 1>,)]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/rvf5)
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Mar/2023 17:56:58] "POST /sing-up HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

This is my class for User:

```py
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    user_name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False, unique=True)
    confirmed = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)
    confirm_cod = db.Column(db.String(100))
    joined_date = db.Column(db.String(100), default=str(formatted_time(datetime.utcnow())))
    posts = relationship("BlogPost", back_populates="author")
    comments = relationship("Comment", back_populates="comment_author")

    def __init__(self, email, password, name, last_name, user_name, confirm_cod):
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
        self.name = name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.user_name = user_name
        self.confirm_cod = confirm_cod
```

and this is the login manager:

```py
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(user_id)
```

this is my sign up function:

```py
@app.route("/sing-up", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def sing_up():
    form = SingUpForm()
    all_users = db.session.query(User).all()
    if form.validate_on_submit() and request.method == "POST":
        # return a list pos 0 is boolean if we got this email or username before will return True
        # if not return False and in pos 1 is a message for the server
        new_user_situation = check_new_user(user_list=all_users,
                                            given_email=form.email.data,
                                            given_username=form.user_name.data)
        if not new_user_situation[0]:
            hash_password = generate_password_hash(form.password.data)
            confirm_cod = generate_confirm_email_number()
            new_user = User(
                email=form.email.data,
                password=hash_password,
                confirm_cod=confirm_cod,
                name=form.first_name.data,
                last_name=form.last_name.data,
                user_name=form.user_name.data,
            )
            db.session.add(new_user)
            db.session.commit()
            load_user(new_user)
            return redirect(url_for("index"))
    return render_template("public/sing-up.html", form=form)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `load_user()` function is expecting an integer `user_id`, but on `sing_up()` you're instead passing an `User` object as parameter.

The correct function call would be `load_user(new_user.id)`.